# How to automate Instagram Reels scheduling? Is there any private API or external scheduling code

Tags: automation, instagram, job-scheduling, instagram-reels

I am making a automatic reels posting python bot. But for that I need a mechanism to schedule my reels. Currently when I run the script, it directly uploads the reels clips.

Comment: The facebook graph API does not allow you to post reels (at least for now).

Comment: I have found the answer for this. It is possible to upload reels using a Python Library 'Instagrapi

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bot without api to schedule the post in Facebook create Studio. When i created and tested the bot the automation was worktfine in that time can upload max of 300 post after that i got "we are unable to Proceess your request" i don't know why, but while doi manually it was working, may be the automa need some time to do it i think so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).